# How to edit html autocomplete in Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, code-snippets

i can't seem to find how to configure the html autocomplete snippet.
i.e: when i write html and hit tab it autocompletes with the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to edit that and make a custom one, is this possible?

Cheers
J

Answer (score 3):

1. Install `Package Resource Viewer` and start it.
2. Open `Resource` -> `HTML` -> `Snippets` -> `html.sublime-snippet`
3. Edit and save.

[image]

Comment: How did you make this tutorial display?

Comment: @CoderJoe, on Mac look for and start `Screenshot` utility or start it via its' shortcut:  `command` + `shift` + `5`, select the region of your screen you want to record and press Record button.